# Music stops when screen rotates using MediaPlayer in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, media, media-player, rotation

I am running into an issue in `Android` where I think I need to keep some sort of reference to a `MediaPlayer` object.

In my `Activity` I begin by instantiating the `MediaPlayer` object and I can begin playing chosen music.  The problem lies when the screen rotates, the Activity gets destroyed, created again, and then I lose reference to the MediaPlayer (since nowhere do I save it).  A new object gets created and the next time the user interacts with the phone, the music stops playing.  What is the proper way of keeping a handle on it?  Should I be?  It's not Serializable so I can't put it in a `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you using service to keep a reference of the MediaPlayer ?

Comment: No, I was playing it directly in the Activity.  Judging by Thorben's upvoted response, it seems like that is the right direction to go in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try putting the `MediaPlayer` in a service, setting up a bind and control it from withing your application.

Comment: This makes total sense, I was just hoping that this could be done from within the activity.  If no one has an answer to solve this from the Activity I will mark yours the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. Since I didn't really need the screen to rotate, I added `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to the activity in the manifest file.